# %1 Is Not a Valid Win32 Application on Apache Server

Tags: windows, perl, apache, winapi

I have Apache 2.2 32bit server running on Windows 7 x64. I need to use perl, so I've installed Strawberry 5.12.3 32bit and configured apache so I have 2 locations:
primary - cgi only and secondary - with mod_perl. My problem is that I can run pages and scripts from the secondary location without any problems, while primary location generates 500 error and errorlog entry saying that:

```
[Wed Dec 12 09:13:10 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 193)%1 is not a valid win32 application.  : couldn't create child process: 720193: login.pl
```

In Windows Event Log I have error 7001. Scripts in console run fine. Have you got any idea what is wrong?

Here is my Apache httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "C:/Apache2_2"

PerlSetEnv NO_CACHE 1
PerlSetEnv DEBUG_SQL 1
Listen 80

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
LoadFile "C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl512.dll"

PerlSwitches -wT -IC:/home/kks/srv/bin

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
        User daemon
        Group daemon
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
ThreadsPerChild 20
ServerAdmin me@me.pl
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2_2/htdocs"
ErrorLog "|perl bin/pipedLogClient.pl -e"
LogLevel warn

SetEnv PERLDB_OPTS "RemotePort=localhost:9000"
SetEnv DBGP_IDEKEY "kks"

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
<IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>
    CustomLog "|perl bin/pipedLogClient.pl -a" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /primary/static/ "C:/home/kks/srv/bin/static/"
    ScriptAlias /primary/ "C:/home/kks/srv/bin/"

#===   primary   ===#

<Location "/primary/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>
<Location "/primary/static/">
        SetHandler default-handler
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>

Alias /secondary/static/ "C:/home/kks/srv/bin/static/"
ScriptAlias /secondary/ "C:/home/kks/srv/bin/"

<Location "/secondary/">
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
        PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
        PerlCleanupHandler owf_cleanup
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Options  +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>

<Location "/secondary/static/">
        SetHandler default-handler
        Options  None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location> 

</IfModule>
```

Comment: My guess: The error message states that you are trying to create a process by calling a weird executable. However, you have no executable called `%1`. Open `login.pl`, and search that file for `open`, `system`, `exec`, `qx()`, backticks and look if something could have gone wrong. You probably just forgot replacing a placeholder with a value, or something. Unrelated to that, the error 7001 is described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278658/en-us), and points to networking problems.

Comment: It is not it - the same happens to any script - event the simplest.

Comment: Another promising link: [problems starting services](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1452.event-id-7001-service-start-operations.aspx).

Comment: probably a new version of dll-hell ;) follow the links from http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1003763  and check the image base for all the dlls involved, and rebase any conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the shebang line in login.pl and make sure the perl there is pointing to the path where you have installed strawberry